# Find values that are the contained in all groups of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a grouping column `Nr` and a column with character values `GRUPPE` - see the example. The number of groups can vary, depending on the choices of the user.

Here a simple example:

```
library(tibble)

Nr <- as.character(c(rep(1,5),rep(2,3),rep(3,4),rep(4,2)))
GRUPPE <- c(c("Cal","Gar","Köf","Fis","Ban"),
          c("Cal","Gar","Köf"),c("Cal","Gar","Ste","Blu"),
          c("Cal","Gar"))

df <- data_frame(Nr,GRUPPE)
```

What I want to find are the values of `GRUPPE`, that are the same in every group (as a vector). In this example it is `c("Cal","Gar")` . The order of the values in the group is not always the same.

If I only had two groups I would use `%in%` , but the number of groups varies. I also don't need a solution for a lot of rows. The practical maximum is approx. 10 groups with maybe 10 Values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`intersect`, split(df$GRUPPE, df$Nr))
#[1] "Cal" "Gar"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `reduce` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
split(df$GRUPPE, df$Nr) %>% 
               reduce(intersect)
#[1] "Cal" "Gar"
```